# Unexpected error in installing Webform_civicrm

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am beginner in drupal.In webform_civicrm installation when i enabled the module in/drupal/modules/ and save configuration i got The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.kindly help to resolve the is

Comment: D7 or D8. Can you pls add a lot more details explaining the versions of civi and webform as well, your installation method etc.

Comment: Also does webform work by itself in drupal?